# Garage wood treatment

Tags: mold

In the future I want to add dry wall and add wire shelving to an unfinished wall in the garage, but I think I need to deal with some pre-existing conditions.

What are my options for treating the mold on the framing in the garage? There's one spot near the garage door and another area on one of the studs in the middle of the wall.

What can I do for controlling humidity so the mold doesn’t return? Currently the garage doesn't have any ventilation or insulation so it gets cold in the winter and stuffy in the summer.

There’s also an area that had some kind of fluid leak, it might be motor oil if I had to guess it was caused by the previous homeowner. Is there anything I should do to it before putting up drywall?

[image]

Comment: Providing some passive ventilation at minimum is a good idea on multiple fronts (mold, poisonous gasses from car exhaust, etc.)  for an unconditioned garage. Vents down low and vents up high...

Comment: Suspected mold should be tested.  Just a couple of places on one piece, I might suspect ink/stain/old mud/dirt.  Mold usually spreads.  If only on one face, might be other stuff.  If mold is found after testing, then a simple bleach spray should kill it.  Then insulation, vapour barrier, drywall, vents should work.